# how to encrypt a string

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, encryption

```
Parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll")
Parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Data.dll")
Parameters.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll")
```

is a way to encrypt "systems.dll" in the add() value?

something like Add(Char64+char45+...) or any method???

```
    Dim Version = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Version.Add("CompilerVersion", "v2.0")

    Dim ICO As String = IO.Path.GetTempPath & "\iCompiler.ico"

    If Icon <> "" Then
        IO.File.Copy(Icon, ICO)
        Parameters.CompilerOptions &= " /win32icon:" & ICO
    End If

    cResults = Compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(Parameters, Source)

    If cResults.Errors.Count > 0 Then
        For Each CompilerError In cResults.Errors
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & CompilerError.ErrorText, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Next
    ElseIf cResults.Errors.Count = 0 Then

    End If
    If Icon <> "" Then : IO.File.Delete(ICO) : End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Transform the string into bytes, and encrypt the bytes.

Comment: @CodeInChaos determine encoding. Use System.Text.Encoding.XXX to extract bytes, then encrypt

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple XOR logic encryption where you take the string, and take a character at a time, XOR it with a key. The output will be the encrypted character. Do this for all characters in the string.

The XOR operator is '^'

To get original string back, use the same key and XOR with the encrypted character, to get the original character.

Google XOR encryption to get more info.

Comment: I wouldn't call that encryption, but just obfuscation, unless the key is the output of a stream cipher(correct IV use assumed) or a one-time pad. Vinere and Caesar are utterly broken nowadays.

Comment: well ur right, specially hard coding the key is susceptible to frequency sniffing. i just though the person needed something quite basic.